# Using a node.js file watcher with JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm, prettier

I've been using Prettier with my projects for a few weeks. I really like it!

I use the JetBrains WebStorm IDE, so I followed these instructions on the Prettier project site for how to set up a file watcher in WebStorm: https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html#using-file-watcher

Then, every time I save a JavaScript file, Prettier automatically runs on it and WebStorm shows me the changes as soon as the file is saved by Prettier.

I want everyone on my team to use Prettier, but not everyone uses WebStorm. Some people use editors that can't be easily configured with Prettier. So, I followed these instructions on the Prettier project site for how to set up a file watcher as an npm script in my `package.json` file: https://prettier.io/docs/en/watching-files.html

```
"scripts": {
  "prettier-watch": "onchange '**/*.js' -- prettier --write {{changed}}"
}
```

I used the `onchange` package as my file watcher, as suggested in the docs, and I disabled the file watcher in WebStorm since I don't need Prettier to run twice in a row.

The problem is that, when I save a file in WebStorm, the `onchange` package runs Prettier correctly, but I don't see the changes in the editor, even when I switch out of and then back into the file window with my mouse cursor. When I try to make a new change, and save again, I get this "File Cache Conflict" warning message from WebStorm: "Changes have been made to  in memory and on disk. Keep Memory Changes, Show difference, Load File System Changes"

[image]

If I choose "Load File System Changes", the version Prettier save successfully loads. But having to see this dialog box every time I save is quite annoying. I would prefer it if the changes were reflected in WebStorm automatically.

It seems like the only way is to use WebStorm's built-in file watcher instead, but then I don't have an easy way to set up Prettier for my coworkers without forcing them to manually install their own independent solutions.

So my question is this: **How can I use a generic node.js file watcher as an npm script that makes changes to my files after saving, and have those changes automatically reloaded in WebStorm without this dialog box?**

Comment: No way; every external change made to file will cause this issue unless you set up the external tool as a file watcher in preferences. The dialog can't be turned off. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-42003

Comment: Okay. It seems like my best option might be to set up the file watcher as an optional script for any developers who want to use it because their editor doesn't have a built-in one.

I followed the instructions for setting up a pre-commit hook which will still enforce the Prettier rules, even if no other developers use the file watcher. (https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and no doubt that dialogue is really annoying and here're the steps that finally helped me resolving the issue.

- Go to Webstorm/Phpstorm Settings/Preferences
- Open up settings for File Watchers: `/Tools/File Watchers/`
- Double click on your file watcher i.e. `Prettier` in this case
- This will open a modal window for editing watcher. Uncheck `Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher`

As per my understanding, unchecking this option will only run file watcher on manually saving the file and will help you getting rid of too much appearance of that modal on every single change. Please don't forget manually saving the file in that case to keep on enjoying Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to fiddle with `Use "safe write"` setting on System settings pane in webstorm

Comment: Good suggestion! I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything. :\

Comment: a very frustrating situation

Comment: usually if I edit an opened file in a different editor (vs code for example or vim), webstorm immediately loads the changes after the file has been saved

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Which OS are you using Webstorm on? I'm on the Mac version.

Comment: definitely I noticed this behaviour in linux, when trying out other editors. I suppose that webstrom should believe that the file is saved for this to work. Because the alert window on your screenshot, in my case only appears when the following happens 1) there are unsaved changes I've made to the file 2) external program (npm for example) made changes at the same time (webstrom doesnt load them in) 3) I hit save and the diff  alert appears

Comment: So it seems like (quite ridiculous of course) that "onchange" program changes the file _before_ webstorm registers the file as saved

Comment: that is why, I think maybe adding '-d 1000' or '-w' or '-p 500' would help